# yEd shows no windows

Tags: java, jre, yed

I want to use the latest yEd graph editor on my machine with Ubuntu 14.04 running on it as the only OS. 
I downloaded yEd installer script for 64-bit Linux. Also:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

yEd installs with no problem, however when I launch the application it only shows me this [window](https://imgur.com/LBj4VtM).

And after clicking on e.g. "New Document" the window closes and nothing else happens. This is while the application shows to be running. The point is that no errors or warnings are shown whatsoever. I am not sure what I should do at this point. Any help is appreciated.

In case you would like to look at the log, it can be found [here](http://txs.io/bUsb).

Iman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that yEd opens on a different workspace, while I have multiple workspaces disabled in the settings under appearance. Therefore, it was not possible to find what was wrong with yEd. Currently, I do not have a fix so it would always open on the current workspace other than manually moving the window.

The other interesting point is that I do not see a similar behaviour when I run the application on my laptop, but my desktop computer with two monitors. This could not be the reason though.